# display flex not work in navigation bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm make a navigation bar there i use flex box but it not responsive. there I'm use position absolute and give width .If i use it without navigation bar it work fine but in navigation bar it not work.

```css
.nav__box{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1200px !important;
        top: 60px;
      }
.nav__box--b1,.nav__box--b2,.nav__box--b3,.nav__box--b4,.nav__box--b5
{
   flex:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">hellow</a>
          <div class="nav__box">
            <div class="nav__box--b1">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b2">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b3">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b4">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b5">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: The question is unclear, what is not working as you intend? Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set fix width on `.nav__box` it's not responsive set `max-width` and remove `position: relative;` from `.navbar-nav > li`.

```css
.navbar-nav > li {
    position: initial !important;
}
.nav__box{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 1200px !important;
        top: 60px;
        width: 100%;
      }
.nav__box--b1,.nav__box--b2,.nav__box--b3,.nav__box--b4,.nav__box--b5
{
   flex:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">hellow</a>
          <div class="nav__box">
            <div class="nav__box--b1">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b2">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b3">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b4">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav__box--b5">
            <ul>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
              <li>ekjffdcee</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
```